# Install npm without installing python2.7

Tags: python, node.js, npm

I want to install npm on my Ubuntu 20.04 and it annoys me that it will install python2.7. I do not need it (at least I think so) as I already have python3.8 nor want it. Is there anyway to install the npm (the .deb file) without python2.7?

Comment: I don't know why npm depends on python

Comment: It is fixed in Ubuntu 21.10 & 22.04, where gyp package depends on python3: https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/gyp

Answer (score -1):

You can using nvm.
Ex:

```bash
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash
bash  # open new terminal
nvm install v18
nvm use v18
```